# Snowflake a task is running with no data affected when calling a procedure

Tags: scheduled-tasks, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

I am having a snowflake task which call a procedure as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK ADD_DATA
    WAREHOUSE = 'DEV_WH'
    TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
    SCHEDULE = '10 MINUTE'
AS
   call MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.AUTOMATED_DATA_UPLOAD('@test_stg', 'ONE_COLUMN_FILE_FORMAT', 'GENERIC_CSV_FORMAT', array_construct('my_survey.csv') );

alter task ADD_DATA resume;
```

When running the procedure by itself:

```
call MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.AUTOMATED_DATA_UPLOAD('@test_stg', 'ONE_COLUMN_FILE_FORMAT', 'GENERIC_CSV_FORMAT', array_construct('my_survey.csv') );
```

It works and add new data.

But when calling it within a task, it won't work and got the following response after resume of course:

The state returned is `succeeded`, no errors returned, and the task is scheduled for the next run.

The procedure is calling 2 other procedures. But this one is the main one.

The user creating this task is the owner and has all required accesses to make it work.

We ran the task over an insert query and it ran normally but with the `call` it didn't.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK ADD_DATA
    WAREHOUSE = 'DEV_WH'
    TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
    SCHEDULE = '10 MINUTE'
AS
   INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(RUNTIME_FIELD) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
```

Comment: I can simply use qualified naming within this procedure. Could I ?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I foud a solution, please check it on my other post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67587175/snowflake-task-is-returning-a-usage-error-that-must-be-granted-to-owner-role/67652034#67652034