# Snowflake task is returning a usage error that must be granted to owner role

Tags: scheduled-tasks, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

I am having a test procedure owned by prod_admin:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
$$
query = "SELECT * FROM DWH_OPS.CHANGE_HISTORY";
stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: query}).execute();
stmt.next();
return stmt;
$$;
```

And a task to run this procedure and owned by task_admin:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK test_procedure
    WAREHOUSE = 'COMPUTE_WH'
    TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
    SCHEDULE = '5 MINUTE'
AS
   call PROD_DB.DWH_OPS.TEST();
```

Once the task is running, we are receiving the following error:

> USAGE privilege on the task's warehouse must be granted to owner role

Both roles are having usage privileges over the same warehouse. We've ran `show grants` to both roles, and they do have access.

When running the procedure using `CALL test()`, it worked using both roles.

Comment: Does the task_admin has  EXECUTE task privilege to the role you used to create the task?

Comment: @hkandpal yep, `execute` is there as well.

Comment: Just to rule out that it is not security, can you create a task in  prod_admin and see if you can call the procedure from there.

Comment: @hkandpal did try it and didn't work. This task is calling a procedure, and this procedure is calling another procedure within its script. All procedures are owned by prod_admin, and prod_admin is owner of the schemas the procedures are work on.

Comment: @hkandpal I answered my question after 2 days of unit testing. Please check it.

Comment: Good nice find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There was 2 issues with my task:**

**Timestamp session format:**

It turned out that this line in our task:

`TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'`

is setting the timestamp of the session into a format that is different than the format within our data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK DATA_LOAD_TASK
    WAREHOUSE = 'COMPUTE_WH'
    // TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
    SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 00 18 * * * Europe/Zurich'
AS
    CALL proc1();
```

As mentioned in the [Snowflake parameters](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html) documentation, this line will set the format during the whole session into the specified format in the task.

By not specifying the format of this parameter, it will set to `AUTO`, which will leave to Snowflake to make necessary timestamp conversions according to field types.

**Ownership and usage over procedures and tasks:**

To work properly with task that is calling a procedure which calling many other, we should grant usage over all used procedures to the role owning the `task`. Even if we are calling one procedure.

```
grant usage on procedure proc1(varchar, varchar, varchar, array) to role prod_taskadmin;
grant usage on procedure proc2(varchar, varchar, varchar, varchar) to role prod_taskadmin;
grant usage on procedure proc3(varchar, varchar, varchar, varchar) to role prod_taskadmin;
```

And the procedures should be owned by a role who have permissions over all the objects in a schema:

```
grant ownership on procedure proc1(string, string, string, array) to role prod_sysadmin;
grant ownership on procedure proc2(string, string, string, array) to role prod_sysadmin;
grant ownership on procedure proc3(string, string, string, array) to role prod_sysadmin;
```